# Rep History mod link broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities

The "Rep History" link on the user mod menu links to (e.g.) https://stackoverflow.com/reputation/user/309308, which returns the "Page Not Found" page

Comment: The fix will be pushed this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a valid page if you are a developer.

We don't expose this to non-developers because it can tell you who voted for what.

Comment: It would make sense, then, that the link in the mod menu should be hidden from non-developers, no?

Comment: Also, what's the danger in moderators knowing who voted for what? Just curious...